# Magento Observer - Check if event was fired from Magento's SOAP API

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer

I am currently developing a custom Magento extension (Magento CE 1.7) that will use the Magento observers, to send data back to a custom ERP solution when certain events are triggered.

However, this ERP solution also uses the Magento SOAP API to update information back to the website (two-way syncing system).

My question is, in my Magento Observer, how can I tell if the following events are being triggered by the Magento SOAP API calls from the ERP versus user interaction in the frontend/backend of the website?

Events I would like to check if being called via API:

- sales_order_save_after
- catalog_product_save_comit_after

I have searched all of the SO boards and seen several similar questions, however none of them appear to have been answered.

Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: Also looking for that answer, found that create a custom SOAP may be a way to accomplish that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24963740/2375207

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going this way;

```
<?php

class My_Module_Model_Observer {

    protected $apiCall;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $request = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest();

        $this->apiCall = false;
        if (
            stripos($request->getRequestUri(), '/api/')
        ) {
            $this->apiCall = true;
        }
    }
```

And then check for `if ($this->apiCall) {}` in my method.